# Angulars $http.post rationale

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

The comparable jQuery function

```
$.post("/example/handler", {foo: 1, bar: 2});
```

will create a request with the post parameters `foo=1&bar=2`. Whereas

```
$http.post("/example/handler", {foo : 1, bar: 2});
```

seems to send a `POST` request with the body `{"foo":1,"bar":2}` rather than the `form-uriencoded` version. To get what I think is the expected behavior here, I need to do something like

```
myModule.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data){
        return _.map(data, function (val, k) { return encodeURI(k) + "=" + encodeURI(val); }).join("&");
    }
});
```

in the module config.

Can anyone explain the rationale behind `$http.post` argument handling? Is there a situation where I'd want Angulars' default behavior, or some hidden advantage I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with the HTTP protocol, but aren't POST requests normally used to send content, not parameters?  Normally, I think GET is used with parameters.

I think you should be able to add a config object to the POST request, and specify the params property:

> params – {Object.} – Map of strings or objects which will be turned to ?key1=value1&key2=value2 after the url. If the value is not a string, it will be JSONified.

So maybe something like this will work:

```
$http.post("/example/handler", {}, {params: {foo: 1, bar: 2} })
```

(Above code snippet is untested... I'm not sure the syntax is correct.)

Comment: For POST requests you don't (typically) send parameters in the url, you send them in the body.  But they do typically use the same key1=value1&key2=value2 format, which is what HTML forms send.

Comment: This does, in fact, work. There's an optional third argument to `$http.post` whose `params` property is serialized into standard POST parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your own question.  Converting a JS object to form encoding takes work and gets tricky for more complicated structures, while converting JS objects to JSON is trivial and therefor default.  What back-end are you using that's having trouble accepting JSON encoding?

Comment: I'm using tornado, and it's not trouble, it's just that I'd have to manually `args = json.loads(self.request.body)` if I were to use what seems to be Angular's default behavior. Most servers I've worked with automatically parse out the standard form-encoded format, while additional work is typically required (either at the front-end or at the back-end) to use JSON in the same context. It seems that a task which both [must typically be done] and [takes work and gets tricky for more complicated structures] is precisely the sort of thing that *should* be handled by an abstraction layer.